# want the app to save the passing screen after a user has passed the test even when the app exits in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, state

I am trying to build a learning app where the user will learn a skill and then give a certain test about it. The problem I am having is that once the user has passed the test, I want the app to always show the passing screen. Meaning, i don't want the app to show the test screen all over everytime the user open the app rather once a test has been passed, the app should permanently store the passing state there. I have no idea how to do it! It would be great if someone helps!

Here's code snippets:

```
export default test =({navigation}) => { 


  const [index, setind] = useState(0);
  const [idis, setidis] = useState(false);
  const [count, setcount] = useState(0);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState('');
  const [disb, setdis] = useState(true);
  const [ndisb, setndis] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
   //Setting callbacks for the process status
   Voice.onSpeechStart = onSpeechStart;
   Voice.onSpeechEnd = onSpeechEnd;
   Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;
   Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;

   return () => {
    //destroy the process after switching the screen
    Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
   
    
  };
}, []);
```

check function for test

```
function Check() {
  if (results.includes(words[index])){
   // console.log(index);
    Alert.alert('Correct!','You are learning so well!');
    
     if(index==7) {
      if(count<5)
      {
            //  Alert.alert('pass','pass');
            // showing passing screen in the form of a modal
            setshowpass(true);
      }
      else{
        Alert.alert('fail','fail');
      }
    }
    if (index==7){
      setndis(true);
      setdis(true);
      setidis(true);
    }
    else{
   setndis(false);
   setdis(true);
   setidis(true);
    }
   
  }
  else{
    Alert.alert('Ops!','Looks like you went wrong somewhere. Try again!');
    setcount(count+1);
    console.log('uc',count);
    setdis(true);
    setndis(true);
   
    if(count==5){
      Alert.alert('Restest', 'Looks like you had way too many mistakes!')
      setind(0);
      setcount(0);
      setdis(true);
    }
  }
}




     const words=['word1', 'wor2', 'word3', 'word4', 'wrd5', 'word6', 'wor7', 'w8'];
      
      
        const [showpass, setshowpass]=useState(false);

return (
    <View style={styles.body}
    >

        <Modal
          transparent={false}
          visible={showpass}
         animationType='slide'
          hardwareAccelerated 
          >
            <View style={styles.body}>
              <Text style={styles.toptext}>Congratulations!</Text>
              <Text style={styles.toptext}>Worked great in Turkishya!</Text>
              <Text style={styles.topptext}>
                And mastered the skill 'Alphabets'
              </Text>
            </View>
            </Modal>
<View>
);
}
```

signup.js:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, Keyboard, ToastAndroid, LogBox} from 'react-native';
import { TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import {Auth} from '../services';

export default signup =({navigation}) => {

    const [userName, setName]= useState()
    const [email,setEmail]= useState()
    const [pass, setpass]=useState()

    return (
        <View style={styles.body}>
            
            <Text style={styles.toptext}>
                Sign Up
            </Text>

            <View style={styles.inputview}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputext}
                placeholderTextColor='#ffffff88'
                placeholder="Enter Your Name"
                keyboardType='default'
                value={userName}
                onChangeText ={e => setName(e)}
            />
            </View>


            <View style={styles.inputview}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputext}
                placeholderTextColor='#ffffff88'
                placeholder="Enter Email"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                value={email}
                onChangeText ={e => setEmail(e)}
            />
            </View>

            <View style={styles.inputview}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputext}
                placeholderTextColor='#ffffff88'
                placeholder="Enter Password"
                secureTextEntry
                value={pass}
                onChangeText ={e => setpass(e)}
            />
            </View>

        
            <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={() => {Auth.signUp(userName, email,pass); LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Given String is empty or null']); ToastAndroid.showWithGravity('Loading...', ToastAndroid.CENTER, ToastAndroid.CENTER); Keyboard.dismiss();}}
                style={styles.button}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttontext}>
                    Sign Up
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <View
                style={{
                    borderBottomColor: '#ffffff99',
                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                    marginLeft:25,
                    marginRight:25,
                    marginTop:25,
                }}
            />
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={styles.lowertext}>
                Already have an account?
                </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                     onPress={() => navigation.navigate('login')}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.nestedtext}>Login Here</Text> 
                </TouchableOpacity>
           
            </View>
        
        </View>
    )
}
```

auth.js:

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const createUserInDb=(uid, fullName, email)=>{
    return firestore().collection('user').doc(uid).set(
        {uid,
        fullName,
        email
        }
    )
}


const signUp = (fullName, email, password) => {
    if(!fullName || !email || !password){
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Please enter all fields!')

    }

    return auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .then (cred => {
        const {uid} =cred.user;
        auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
        displayName: fullName
    })
    return uid
    })
    .then(
        uid => createUserInDb(uid, fullName, email)
    )
   .catch(
       err => Alert.alert (err.code,err.message)
   )
}

const signIn = (email, password) => {
    if  (!email || !password){
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Please enter all fields')
    }
    return auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(()=> {})
    .catch(
        err => Alert.alert(err.code,err.message)
    )
}

const forgetPassword =(email) => {
    if(!email){
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Please enter Email!')
    }

    return auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
    .then(()=> {
        return Alert.alert('Link Sent on Given Email!', 'Check your Email. A password reset link has been sent.')
    })
    .catch(
        err => Alert.alert(err.code,err.message)
    )

}

const signOut = () => {
    return auth().signOut()
}


const Auth = {
    signUp,
    signIn,
    forgetPassword,
    signOut
}

export default Auth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like this should usually be handled on the server. However, you could make this persistent on the phone using the [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage).

**Storage functionality**

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

// or whatever
const key = "hasPassed"

export const hasPassed = async () => {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then(result => result != null ? JSON.parse(result) : undefined).catch(e => console.log(e))    
}

export const setHasPassed = async (newPassed) => {
    return AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({hasPassed: newPassed})).catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

Then, use it in your screens as follows.

```js
// or whatever name it is
const MainScreen = () => {

   const [showpass, setshowpass] = useState();
   
   useEffect(() => {
       const getState = async () => {
           const result = await hasPassed()
           setshowpass(result ? result.hasPassed : false)
       }
       getState()
   }, [])

   // since it is async
   if (showpass === undefined) {
      return null
   }

   return (
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <Modal
           transparent={false}
           visible={showpass}
           animationType='slide'
           hardwareAccelerated 
         >
            <View style={styles.body}>
              <Text style={styles.toptext}>Congratulations!</Text>
              <Text style={styles.toptext}>Worked great in Turkishya!</Text>
              <Text style={styles.topptext}>
                And mastered the skill 'Alphabets'
              </Text>
            </View>
            </Modal>
      <View>
   );
}
```

If you set the state, just save it in the local storage as well as follows.

```js
if(count<5) {
  //  Alert.alert('pass','pass');
  // showing passing screen in the form of a modal
   setHasPassed(true).then(() => setshowpass(true))
}
```

Comment: but wait! I am having some serious problem. Now, even if a completely new user signs in, there's no test sheet showing up meaning even for an absolute new user, directly the passing screen is popping up, there's no test sheet! I wanted the state preservation for specific user only that is logged in at the time and when the new user logs in, he gets his own test sheet until he passes the test what do i do now? Looking forward to your reply!

Comment: If you sign in with different users on the same phone, then you need a user management. each user needs its own id and each id must be integrated in the key for the settings. If your server provides you with an user object ,e.g.  an unique id, then just change the `key` constant to this key.

Comment: can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: How does your login process look like? I guess you have some unique identifier for each user. Use this identifier as the key string ("hasPassed" -> unique identifier in the key constant).

Comment: i am adding my signup.js and auth.js code in the question, can you tell me how can i access my uid from there?

Comment: `auth().currentUser.uid` provides you with the uuid of the current user. Change the settings key from `"hasPassed"` to `auth().currentUser.uid + "hasPassed"` and you are done.

Comment: nope! unfortunately, its still acting the same :( showing the passing screen even for a new user

Comment: the app do react correctly but only if i rewrite/refreshes the code, otherwise it keeps reacting according to the previously logged in user

Comment: Try defining the key constant inside the component itself and pass it as a parameter to the function of otherwise auth.currentUser will never update to the newest value